# Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined - JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I get this error (Cannot read property 'menu_link' of undefined) because the query to my DB MySql doesn't find a result. How do I manage this problem?

```
var sql = "SELECT menu_link FROM shops WHERE id_shop="+ id_user +"";
   db.query(sql, function(shops_error, shops, shop_fields){
     if (shops_error) {
        winston.error(shops_error);
     }else {
       res.render('menu.ejs', { menu_link: shops[0].menu_link});
     }
   });
```

Comment: The usual first step is to do `console.log(shops)` and see what you actually have there.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access a property of an undefined value will always lead to a `TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined`.

Normally you would want to check the result, assign it a default value if `undefined`, and pass it into the `render` method, but there are some shorthand ways of doing this.

If you are on a recent version of `Node`, 14 or above, you can use optional chaining and it will resolve the entire value to `undefined`. You can pair that with the `nullish coalescing` operator to assign a default value

```js
     } else {
       res.render('menu.ejs', { menu_link: shops[0]?.menu_link ?? 'default'});
     }
```

You can also use the `ternary` operator

```js
     } else {
       res.render('menu.ejs', { menu_link: shops[0] ? shops[0].menu_link : 'default' });
     }
```